How can I correct the error in HTTPS server python code?
The following command generates the keys needed for HTTPS connection:
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout privkey.pem -out cert.pem -days 365

Below is the code, I use for project found on internet. But I get several errors:
simple-https-server.py:
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler
import ssl


httpd = HTTPServer(('localhost', 4446), BaseHTTPRequestHandler)

httpd.socket = ssl.wrap_socket (httpd.socket, 
        keyfile="privkey.pem", 
        certfile='cert.pem', server_side=True)

httpd.serve_forever()

$ python simple-https-server.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 1020, in _create
    self.getpeername()
OSError: [Errno 128] Transport endpoint is not connected

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cemfa/programs/html/gaming/backup/html/simple-https-server.py", line 7, in <module>
    httpd.socket = ssl.wrap_socket (httpd.socket,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 1439, in wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 501, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 1032, in _create
    notconn_pre_handshake_data = self.recv(1)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 1262, in recv
    return super().recv(buflen, flags)
BlockingIOError: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable


Can you reason why this does happen?
Edit:
I need administrator rights for low level networking. I tried out this code above in cygwin, which is a linux emulator and I had no success. Later on, I gave try on windows python. Now it works as expected.

I run your code on LInux and it starts without error. Command getpeername() may suggest that it has problem with your network. socket — Low-level networking interface — Python 3.12.4 documentation

I suppose I must have administrator rights for low level networking . I will try it with root rights. TY for comment.
